# Python Pip Install Pandas Stuck at Version 1.1.5 on CentOS7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, linux, centos

For practical reason, I am forced to use CentOS 7 in my case. I have Python3.10 installed and as I tried `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` it just won't upgrade and it will get stuck at Version 1.1.5.

As I `pip3 show pandas` it however shows that the location is `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. Somehow even when I thought I am using python3.10, the pandas thing is actually in a python3.6 folder. I supposed this is because some time ago python was installed through `dnf`, and it seems for some reasons `dnf` can only install python3.6, and then the `pip3` I used just identify itself with python3.6 rather than the python3.10 I have.

May I know what I can do in this case?